# Make ctrl+space more like Eclipse

Tags: sublimetext2

In the Default (OSX).sublime-keymap file, I see:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "auto_complete" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "replace_completion_with_auto_complete", "context":
        [
            { "key": "last_command", "operator": "equal", "operand": "insert_best_completion" },
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false },
            { "key": "setting.tab_completion", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
    },
```

But I'd like it to function more like Eclipse, where methods available get popped up after hitting `.` and waiting for a split second. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that Sublime Text is not an IDE. As such, Eclipse like completion (where it only brings up methods that you can call for the particular variable) is not built in. You may try something like [SublimeJava](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeJava) for completions more like Eclipse. I have used it a bit, with mixed results. It did not work as well as Eclipse, but for what I was doing, it was acceptable. To bring up your current set of completions (from within the file by default) when you press ".", you may add the following to your User Preferences (accessible through `Preferences -> Settings - User`).

```
"auto_complete_triggers": [{"selector": "source.java", "characters": "."}]
```

This will cause the auto complete pop up to be displayed when ever you enter `.` in java files.